# Let the n^{th} term of the fibonacci series be a_n and that of lucas series be b_n. prove that a_{2n) = a_n * b_n.

Tags: sequences-and-series

[Please solve for 5. ii](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndHTy.jpg)

This question must be solve by principle of induction.

Comment: Hello, SE is not a place to do your homework. Please shown us your effort first and your progress.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960

Comment: Sorry this is the first time i am asking a question. I did not want to just do my homework. I tried the question but without success.